# SVM prediction in R

Tags: r, svm

I have some problem when using svm function.
Here is what I tried.

The column I try to predict is Find1 in the first column of my dataframe.

In my prediction and table(p2,test[,1]) I have some numbers of my second column of my table, I don't understand why

```
train = Fulltable4[1:1500,]
test = Fulltable4[1501:2000,]

svmfit = svm(Find1~ ., train , kernel = 'linear' )
p2 = predict(svmfit,test, type = "class")
table(p2,test[,1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare your output like this (instead of `table(p2,test[,1])`):

```
cbind(p2,Find1=test[,1])
            p2     Find1
1501  99.89779 105.73247
1502  99.68132  79.71067
1503 100.65951 106.80993
1504  98.40910  88.14096
1505 100.94231 103.91829
1506 100.97101 100.64119
...
1998  99.53338  79.23626
1999 100.44851 113.98020
2000 100.32326  93.40185
```

My toy input dataset:

```
Fulltable4<-data.frame(Find1=rnorm(2000,100,10),y1=rnorm(2000,100,90),y2=rnorm(2000,100,90),y3=rnorm(2000,100,90),y4=rnorm(2000,100,90))
```